# reading CSV files over multiple days but missing some days

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, csv, dataframe

hello I am reading CSV files over multiple days but some days may be missing because the data is non existent.

How can I introduce an `if condition` or a `catch error` in the code below to tell the program to go ahead reading the next date when the data of current date does not exist.

```
dfsEuro = [pd.read_csv("/usr/local/brs/BLK/Markit/tobfm/DXOpen_BuysideAnalytics_EuroEqty_SF_" + xDate[i] + ".tsv",
                          sep="\t") for i in range(0, len(runDates))]
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.isfile` to check if file exist.

**Ex:**

```
import os


dfsEuro = []
for i in range(0, len(runDates)):
    file_name = "/usr/local/brs/BLK/Markit/tobfm/DXOpen_BuysideAnalytics_EuroEqty_SF_" + xDate[i] + ".tsv"
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):    #Check if file exists
        dfsEuro.append(pd.read_csv(file_name,sep="\t"))
```